# The continuity of $u(x)=x^p$ on the interval $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, real-numbers

I have the following problem:

> *"Consider the function $u(x)=x^p,\, p\in \mathbb R$. For which values of $p$ is $u\in C[0,1]$?"*

Now, I understand that if $p<0$ then $x^p$ blows up at $x=0$, and so is not continuous at the same point. But in the solution to this problem it says that:

> *"... is therefore not continuous **on the whole interval** $[0,1]$"*

Why is it the whole interval and not just at the point $x=0$?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being "*continuous on the whole interval*" means, by definition, being continuous at **every** point of the interval. So, if your function is not continuous at just one point, it won't be continuous on the **whole** interval.

It will still be continuous on the interval $(0,1]$, for instance.